# How to select distinct by 2 fields

Tags: sql, database, group-by, distinct

I need to be able to only select records which have an IsActive = 1 in addition to all of this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 0 as CommunityID,  

                    CASE Libname
                        WHEN 'RKHL' THEN 'ROCK HILL'
                        WHEN 'FTML' THEN 'FORT MILL'
                        WHEN 'LANC' THEN 'LANCASTER'
                        WHEN 'BREV' THEN 'BREVARD'
                        WHEN 'PBTC' THEN 'MIDLANDS-CLEC'
                        WHEN 'PBTI' THEN 'MIDLANDS-ILEC'

                    END AS CommunityDesc,

                    LibName,
                    LibName + '|' AS FilterByID,
                    IsActive 
                    FROM Reference.dbo.Community
                    WHERE LibName <> 'CAROTEL' 
                    UNION
                    SELECT CommunityID, RTRIM(COMMNAME) AS CommunityDesc, LibName, LibName + '|' + RTRIM(COMMNAME) AS FilterByID, IsActive
                    FROM Reference.dbo.Community 

                    WHERE LibName <> 'CAROTEL'
                    ORDER BY 1,3;
```

Comment: Could you be more clear about what your question is?

Comment: You should try using a `GROUP BY` for multiple columns, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns-postgresql

Comment: In addition to having the Community ID be 0, I also need all of the data returned to have IsActive to be 1. I have tried to do a SELECT DISTINCT 0 as CommunityID UNION SELECT DISTINCT 1 as IsActive, but that didnt work. I also dont know if GROUP BY is applicable here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `IsActive=1` to the WHERE clause on both sides of the Union.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the result set in this way :

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT 0 as CommunityID,  

                    CASE Libname
                        WHEN 'RKHL' THEN 'ROCK HILL'
                        WHEN 'FTML' THEN 'FORT MILL'
                        WHEN 'LANC' THEN 'LANCASTER'
                        WHEN 'BREV' THEN 'BREVARD'
                        WHEN 'PBTC' THEN 'MIDLANDS-CLEC'
                        WHEN 'PBTI' THEN 'MIDLANDS-ILEC'

                    END AS CommunityDesc,

                    LibName,
                    LibName + '|' AS FilterByID,
                    IsActive 
                    FROM Reference.dbo.Community
                    WHERE LibName <> 'CAROTEL' 
                    UNION
                    SELECT CommunityID, RTRIM(COMMNAME) AS CommunityDesc, LibName, LibName + '|' + RTRIM(COMMNAME) AS FilterByID, IsActive
                    FROM Reference.dbo.Community 

                    WHERE LibName <> 'CAROTEL'
) i
WHERE IsActive = 1
ORDER BY 1,3;
```